# Spring @cachable - view cached data

Tags: spring, caching

One of my requirements requires to see how much data i have cached

I would like to see what data is cached in Spring.

Is there any way i can see what Spring cached? key and values

Comment: why not expose via jmx and view via jconsole/jvisualVM?

Answer (score 6):

Well if you have a handle on the CacheManager

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html

it has a method:

```
getCache(String name)
```

which returns a:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html

which has a method:

```
getNativeCache();
```

which you should then be able to query.

Comment: more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59943335/26510