# Caffeine Cache in Spring Boot Cache : Get all cached keys

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache, caffeine-cache

I'm using Caffeine Cache library for Spring Cache. Is there a way to get all the cached keys?

My current application works on a near-realtime data, with the flow as :

[image]

In the `Cache Updater Thread`(which runs at a fixed interval, irrespective of the user request), I need to get all the keys currently in the Cache, fetch their latest data from Db & then use `@CachePut` to update the cache.

Comment: Can you please reference me with a good example for the implemantation. I am on my way to implement the same.

Comment: Hello @Einstein_AB, I'll suggest you to go through the spring cache [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html). If you are specifically using Caffeine cache, you can refer to [this](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-with-caffeine-cache/) example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yo can inject CacheManager and obtain native cache from it.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
class Test {
  private CacheManager cacheManager;

  Set<Object> keys(String cacheName){
    CaffeineCache caffeineCache = (CaffeineCache) cacheManager.getCache(cacheName);
    com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Cache<Object, Object> nativeCache = caffeineCache.getNativeCache();
    return nativeCache.asMap().keySet();
  }

}
```

Of course you should add some class casting checks.

Comment: As a follow up to this. It's important to note that CaffeineCache Impliments Cache, so this casting is natural. Any other cache type implementing Cache should be castable this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can return keyset by using asMap().keySet() method as follows.

```
import com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Cache;
import com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine;

class Test{
private Cache<String,String> testCache;
Test(){
 testCache = Caffeine.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite( 3000, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
}
     
// return keys as a set
public Set<String> getCacheKeySet(){
return testCache.asMap().keySet();
}
```